# Center last element if it's last and alone in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a bootstrap grid where the content is loaded dynamically.
If the last element is alone in the row it should be centered.

What i want:

```
A   B
C   D
E   F
  G
```

HTML Code:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">b</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">c</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">d</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">e</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">f</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">g</div>
</div>
```

What i get:

```
A   B
C   D
E   F
G
```

I tried it with the css selector `:nth-last-of-type()`, but with this selector every 'last element' gets the properties.

Anyone know how to do this? I hope i could explain it in a way you can understand it.

Comment: do you want to do this with CSS or JavaScript, also what would the behaviour be if there is only 1 item. Will it center or float left?

Comment: have you tried adding "col-md-offset-3" class to the last div of your template (as i suggest in my answer :P )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining last-child and nth child would work, then you can position your element centrally. This example uses left 50% transform:translateX(-50%);

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPNWxK

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

div {
  height:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:blue;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}

div:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:red;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%); 
}
```

When you actually do this don't use the div as the actual selector of course

Comment: Thanks for your help! This does exactly what i want!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 7):

It's simple, you can use `display:flex` and `text-align: center`.

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks! But i would prefer mthomps answer, because is much less code.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine :nth-child(odd) and :last-child to check if the element is the last in the row by itself like this:

CSS:

```
.row {
  width: 200px;
}
.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.col-md-6:nth-child(odd):last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">a</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">b</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">c</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">d</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">e</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">f</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">g</div>
</div>
```

[Here's a Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaLxzb).

Comment: Well of course, if that's not the expected behaviour then he just needs some unique identifier class/ID at .row level, but I think his question was more "how do I tell if this element is on the last row by itself or not".

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the last one is odd (so it will be alone in that row) you can use bootstrap offsetting system and write it like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
```

ref: [Bootstrap OffSet](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Just `text-align: center` the `last-child` `div`, as below.

Open the snippet in full page mode to see the result as you wanted

```css
div:last-child{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">D</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">E</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">F</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">G</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple in that way:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for :last-child selector

Comment: The problem is that :last-child will apply regardless of whether there is one or two items in the final row.